# Make soft word wrap not cut words in the middle of the line?

Tags: spacemacs, wrapping

Currently, in text files, Emacs is wrapping text (soft wrap), but if a word is at the end of the line, then it puts half of the word at the end of the line and the second half at the beginning of the next line.

Is there a way to make it not cut words across lines like this (i.e. put the whole word at the beginning of the next line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual line mode does this. See the info node `(emacs) Visual Line Mode` in the Emacs manual for details. You can turn it on with `M-x visual-line-mode`.